Infinite loop when iterating through std::unordered_map and continuously increasing memory
i was trying to solve this problem on leetcode.
Majority Element - LeetCode

Given an array nums of size n, return the majority element.
The majority element is the element that appears more than ⌊n / 2⌋ times. You may assume that the majority element always exists in the array.

Input: nums = [3,2,3]
Output: 3
Input: nums = [2,2,1,1,1,2,2]
Output: 2

but i wrote the solution and i am getting memory limit exceeded and i dont know why can you please help me with this?
class Solution {
public:
    int majorityElement(vector<int>& nums) {
        unordered_map<long long,int>hash;
        for(int i = 0; i<nums.size(); i++)
        {
            hash[nums[i]]++; 
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<hash.size();i++)
        {
            if(hash[i]>(nums.size()/2))
            return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
};


Which are the constraint of size?

I'd be more worried about the logic flaw in your code. What do you think the size of the map has to do with the keys contained in the map? Your second loop is incorrect.

There is an algo with O(1) memory and complexity O(n), one pass to select a candidate, one pass to verify the candidate.

Naïve algorithms are rarely the expected one in LeetCode problem

you can sort the vector and then traverse it once and count. still not the best, though there are many ways to use less memory than your approach

Your code is valid c++ and does what it is supposed to outside of leetcode - this is a leetcode issue not c++.

Have you tried asking on the leetcode forums you have an algorithm problem NOT a C++ problem.

If there is a very obvious straightforward algorithm to solve a programming competition problem, you can be almost sure that the parameters of the judge are tuned to weed out solutions using such algorithms.

@n.m.couldbeanAI no, they don't even do that well. It's actually depressing to think about.

The reason you are running out of memory is because the hash map grows indefinitely. This is due to the way you are trying to loop though the map.
Accessing map values with the square brackets like hash[i] adds a new key if the key does not exist yet. This increases the size of the map meaning that i<hash.size() never becomes false and your loop won't terminate until the map is so big you start running into memory issues.
Looping through a map can be done as follows:
for (auto it = hash.begin(); it != hash.end(); it++) {
    it->first // key
    it->second // value
}

// Or
for (auto&& [key,value] : hash) { }


@D.Malim the problem is you didn't  explain the reason for the change and how that changed the memory usage.

"never becomes true " isnt completely correct. There are cases where the loop eventually terminates. https://godbolt.org/z/9sbEq7cj8. Its only the cases when hash[hash.size()] was not populated already before the loop that the loop is infinite, I think... not totally sure about the condition

The whole idea of this task is not to use containers at all. That is why memory limit in this task is lowered.
There is algorithm called "heavy hitter" (generalization of Boyer-Moore_majority_vote_algorithm) which can solve this task in O(n) time and with O(1) memory complexity. This is also why the task description is so strange:
Majority Element - LeetCode

Given an array nums of size n, return the majority element.
The majority element is the element that appears more than ⌊n / 2⌋ times. You may assume that the majority element always exists in the array.

